# Custom slider control in MFC (visual studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, slider

I am making a slider control in visual studio in MFC, I want to set the range from 14 to 100 and step size should be 0.25 as 14.25, 14.50, 14.75 .

How can can make an custom slider control?

Comment: Make a slider with a range from 0 to (100-14) * 4. The rest is basic basic school math.

Comment: You're going to find it much easier (possible, in fact)to make the range from 56-400 (or 0-344) in steps of 1, then do the math to fractionalize the value whenever you read it.  Caveat: it's been *forever* since I did custom controls in win32, but as I recall sliders require integer representation for their ranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`CSliderCtrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/csliderctrl-class) wraps a [trackbar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/trackbar-control-reference) control. As such, the former shares the same limitations with the latter. Specifically, the range is set through the [`TBM_SETRANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tbm-setrange) message (or the [`TBM_SETRANGEMIN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tbm-setrangemin) and [`TBM_SETRANGEMAX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tbm-setrangemax) messages). Either message takes an integral value, so you cannot have the control operate on fractional values.

If you need the integral values supported by the control to represent fractional values, you will have to perform the mapping in client code (scaling and translation). Possible mappings are:

- Set the range from `0 * 4` to `(100 - 14) * 4` (i.e. `0` to `344`). The control position `x` represents the value `14 + x / 4`.
- Set the range from `14 * 4` to `100 * 4` (i.e. `56` to `400`). The control position `x` then represents the value `x / 4`.

In general, fractional values cannot accurately be represented when using floating point values. In this case, however, there is no loss in accuracy; any integer value divided by a power-of-two (such as 4) can be accurately represented by a floating point value (so long as the result is still in range).